# continuous random variable example

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Let $x$ be a random variable with the following distribution function $f$:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{1}{2x}, & \text{ if } 0 \leq x \leq 2 \\          
                  0, & \text{ elsewhere }
         \end{cases}$$

P(1 <= X <= 1.5) = limit 1.5 and 1, 1/2x dx = 1/4 dx^2 ] 1.5 and 1 = 5/16

I do not get how they got 5/16?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
P(1 \leq X \leq 1.5) & = \int_{1}^{1.5} f(x)\, dx \\
& = \int_{1}^{1.5} \dfrac{1}{2}x \, dx = \dfrac{1}{2} \left[ \dfrac{x^{2}}{2}\right]_{1}^{1.5} = \dfrac{1}{4}(2.25 - 1) = \dfrac{1.25}{4} = \dfrac{5/4}{4} = \dfrac{5}{16}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The shaded area is a trapezoid. The two bases of the trapezoid have lengths of $f(1) = \dfrac{1}{2}$ and $f(1.5) = \dfrac{3}{4}$. The height of the trapezoid is $1.5-1 = \dfrac{1}{2}$.

So the area is $A = \dfrac{1}{2}(b_1+b_2)h = \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{3}{4}\right)\cdot\dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{5}{16}$.